# Command-line Unix ASCII-based charting / plotting tool

Tags: unix, charts, graph, matplotlib

Is there a good command-line UNIX charting / graphing / plotting tool out there?  I'm looking for something that will plot xy points on an ASCII graph.

Just to clarify, I'm looking for something that will output a graph in ASCII (like ascii-art style), so I can use it over an interactive shell session without needing X.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Comment: Also have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55347194/1147688).

Comment: [How to plot a chart in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37288421/7758804)

Comment: I feel a bit sorry for the OP that at the time of posting, there was probably nothing. Today there are some really good options.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Try [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). It has very powerful graphing possibilities.

It can output to your terminal in the following way:

```
gnuplot> set terminal dumb
Terminal type set to 'dumb'
Options are 'feed 79 24'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)

   1 ++----------------**---------------+----**-----------+--------**-----++
     +                *+ *              +   *  *          +  sin(x) ****** +
 0.8 ++              *    *                *    *                *    *   ++
     |               *    *                *    *                *    *    |
 0.6 ++              *     *              *      *              *      *  ++
     *              *       *             *       *             *      *   |
 0.4 +*             *       *             *       *             *      *  ++
     |*            *        *            *        *            *        *  |
 0.2 +*            *        *            *        *            *        * ++
     | *          *          *          *          *          *          * |
   0 ++*          *          *          *          *          *          *++
     |  *         *           *         *           *         *           *|
-0.2 ++ *         *           *         *           *         *           *+
     |   *       *            *        *            *        *            *|
-0.4 ++  *       *            *        *            *        *            *+
     |   *      *              *      *              *      *              *
-0.6 ++  *      *              *      *              *      *             ++
     |    *     *               *     *               *    *               |
-0.8 ++    *   *                 *   *                *    *              ++
     +     *  *        +         *  *   +              *  *                +
  -1 ++-----**---------+----------**----+---------------**+---------------++
    -10               -5                0                 5                10
```

Comment: What does the `options are feed 79 24'` message mean? Is that height and width? Can you expand your example to set them?

Comment: @einpoklum: That is the default size of the plot, which refers to vga nr of character columns and lines. (Lookup dumb in the gnuplot docx)

Answer (score 76):

While `gnuplot` is powerful, it's also really irritating when you just want to pipe in a bunch of points and get a graph.

Thankfully, someone created [eplot](https://github.com/chriswolfvision/eplot) (easy plot), which handles all the nonsense for you.

It doesn't seem to have an option to force terminal graphs; I patched it like so:

```
--- eplot.orig  2012-10-12 17:07:35.000000000 -0700
+++ eplot       2012-10-12 17:09:06.000000000 -0700
@@ -377,6 +377,7 @@
                # ---- print the options
                com="echo '\n"+getStyleString+@oc["MiscOptions"]
                com=com+"set multiplot;\n" if doMultiPlot
+               com=com+"set terminal dumb;\n"
                com=com+"plot "+@oc["Range"]+comString+"\n'| gnuplot -persist"
                printAndRun(com)
                # ---- convert to PDF
```

An example of use:

```
[$]> git shortlog -s -n | awk '{print $1}' | eplot 2> /dev/null


  3500 ++-------+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------++
       +        +       +        "/tmp/eplot20121012-19078-fw3txm-0" ****** +       *                                                                    |  3000 +*                                                                  ++       |*                                                                   |       | *                                                                  |  2500 ++*                                                                 ++       | *                                                                  |
       |  *                                                                 |
  2000 ++ *                                                                ++
       |  **                                                                |
  1500 ++   ****                                                           ++
       |        *                                                           |
       |         **                                                         |
  1000 ++          *                                                       ++
       |            *                                                       |
       |            *                                                       |
   500 ++            ***                                                   ++
       |                **************                                      |
       +        +       +        +    **********  +        +       +        +
     0 ++-------+-------+--------+--------+-----***************************++
       0        5       10       15       20      25       30      35       40
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted -- piping to to gnuplot!

Comment: Does eplot still need that patch?

Comment: [The latest version](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/eplot/index.html#download) was released in 2007, so yes.  A better patch that might actually get released would involve adding another flag and conditionalizing the behavior, but I haven't yet wanted to put in the effort to do that.

Comment: I've put a fork of eplot up on github with the patch suggested in this thread, and also added iTerm2 inline image display. https://github.com/dandavison/eplot

Comment: I sent Christian Wolf, the eplot creator, a patch and he accepted it.  New repo on github: https://github.com/chriswolfvision/eplot

Comment: Worth noting that the `eplot` option to output to terminal is `-d`.

Comment: `git shortlog -s -n | awk '{print $1}' | gnuplot -e 'set term dumb; pl "-"'`. I don't think it is "irritating" and worth to install another package.

Answer (score 30):

See also: [asciichart](https://github.com/kroitor/asciichart) (implemented in Node.js and [ported](https://github.com/kroitor/asciichart#ports) to Python,  Java, [Go](https://github.com/guptarohit/asciigraph) and Haskell)

[image]

Comment: very promising and nice charts just that I don't want to add another package manager just for one tool. I don't use npm that often...

Comment: @stucash you can get it in a single file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kroitor/asciichart/master/asciichart.js or from CDN, no need to install anything: https://github.com/kroitor/asciichart/

Comment: This is the best one I've found.

Answer (score 29):

Another option I've just run across is [bashplotlib](https://github.com/glamp/bashplotlib).  Here's an example run on (roughly) the same data as [my eplot example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12868778/120999):

```
[$]> git shortlog -s -n | awk '{print $1}' | hist

 33|   o
 32|   o
 30|   o
 28|   o
 27|   o
 25|   o
 23|   o
 22|   o
 20|   o
 18|   o
 16|   o
 15|   o
 13|   o
 11|   o
 10|   o
  8|   o
  6|   o
  5|   o
  3|   o o     o
  1|   o o     o o       o
  0|   o o o o o o       o
    ----------------------

-----------------------
|       Summary       |
-----------------------
|   observations: 50  |
| min value: 1.000000 |
|  mean : 519.140000  |
|max value: 3207.000000|
-----------------------
```

Adjusting the bins helps the resolution a bit:

```
[$]> git shortlog -s -n | awk '{print $1}' | hist --nosummary --bins=40

 18|   o
   |   o
 17|   o
 16|   o
 15|   o
 14|   o
 13|   o
 12|   o
 11|   o
 10|   o
  9|   o
  8|   o
  7|   o
  6|   o
  5|   o   o
  4|   o   o o
  3|   o o o o   o
  2|   o o o o   o
  1|   o o o o   o                     o       o
  0|   o o o o o o           o     o   o o   o o                                 o
   |   o o o o o o           o     o   o o   o o                                 o
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: to make `hist` available, run `pip install bashplotlib` (or my preference is to run `pipx install bashplotlib`)

Answer (score 26):

[feedgnuplot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/feedgnuplot.1.html) is another front end to gnuplot, which handles piping in data.

```
    $ seq 5 | awk '{print 2*$1, $1*$1}' |
      feedgnuplot --lines --points --legend 0 "data 0" --title "Test plot" --y2 1 \
                  --terminal 'dumb 80,40' --exit

                                     Test plot

     10 ++------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+------*A 25
        +       +        +       +       +       +        +       +    **#+
        |       :        :       :       :       :        : data 0+**A*** |
        |       :        :       :       :       :        :       :** #   |
      9 ++.......................................................**.##....|
        |       :        :       :       :       :        :    ** :#      |
        |       :        :       :       :       :        :  **   #       |
        |       :        :       :       :       :        :**   ##:      ++ 20
      8 ++................................................A....#..........|
        |       :        :       :       :       :      **:   #   :       |
        |       :        :       :       :       :    **  : ##    :       |
        |       :        :       :       :       :  **    :#      :       |
        |       :        :       :       :       :**      B       :       |
      7 ++......................................**......##................|
        |       :        :       :       :    ** :    ##  :       :      ++ 15
        |       :        :       :       :  **   :   #    :       :       |
        |       :        :       :       :**     : ##     :       :       |
      6 ++..............................*A.......##.......................|
        |       :        :       :    ** :     ##:        :       :       |
        |       :        :       :  **   :    #  :        :       :       |
        |       :        :       :**     :  ##   :        :       :      ++ 10
      5 ++......................**........##..............................|
        |       :        :    ** :      #B       :        :       :       |
        |       :        :  **   :    ## :       :        :       :       |
        |       :        :**     :  ##   :       :        :       :       |
      4 ++...............A.......###......................................|
        |       :      **:     ##:       :       :        :       :       |
        |       :    **  :   ##  :       :       :        :       :      ++ 5
        |       :  **    : ##    :       :       :        :       :       |
        |       :**    ##B#      :       :       :        :       :       |
      3 ++.....**..####...................................................|
        |    **####      :       :       :       :        :       :       |
        |  **## :        :       :       :       :        :       :       |
        B**     +        +       +       +       +        +       +       +
      2 A+------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+------++ 0
        1      1.5       2      2.5      3      3.5       4      4.5      5
```

You can install it on Debian and Ubuntu by running `sudo apt install feedgnuplot` .

Comment: How does this compare with `eplot`, suggested in another answer?

Comment: You can get Unicode characters by passing `--terminal 'caca 80,40'`, although it requires Gnuplot to have been compiled with libcaca

Answer (score 20):

Plots in a single line are really simple, and can help one *see* patterns of highs and lows.
See also [pysparklines](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysparklines).
(Does anyone know of unicode slanting lines, which could be fit together to make
line, not bar, plots ?)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

__version__ = "2015-01-02 jan  denis"


#...............................................................................
def onelineplot( x, chars=u"▁▂▃▄▅▆▇█", sep=" " ):
    """ numbers -> v simple one-line plots like

f ▆ ▁ ▁ ▁ █ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁  osc 47  ▄ ▁ █ ▇ ▄ ▆ ▅ ▇ ▇ ▇ ▇ ▇ ▄ ▃ ▃ ▁ ▃ ▂  rosenbrock
f █ ▅ █ ▅ █ ▅ █ ▅ █ ▅ █ ▅ █ ▅ █ ▅ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁  osc 58  ▂ ▁ ▃ ▂ ▄ ▃ ▅ ▄ ▆ ▅ ▇ ▆ █ ▇ ▇ ▃ ▃ ▇  rastrigin
f █ █ █ █ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁ ▁  osc 90  █ ▇ ▇ ▁ █ ▇ █ ▇ █ ▇ █ ▇ █ ▇ █ ▇ █ ▇  ackley

Usage:
    astring = onelineplot( numbers [optional chars= sep= ])
In:
    x: a list / tuple / numpy 1d array of numbers
    chars: plot characters, default the 8 Unicode bars above
    sep: "" or " " between plot chars

How it works:
    linscale x  ->  ints 0 1 2 3 ...  ->  chars ▁ ▂ ▃ ▄ ...

See also: https://github.com/RedKrieg/pysparklines
    """

    xlin = _linscale( x, to=[-.49, len(chars) - 1 + .49 ])
        # or quartiles 0 - 25 - 50 - 75 - 100
    xints = xlin.round().astype(int)
    assert xints.ndim == 1, xints.shape  # todo: 2d
    return sep.join([ chars[j] for j in xints ])


def _linscale( x, from_=None, to=[0,1] ):
    """ scale x from_ -> to, default min, max -> 0, 1 """
    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    m, M = from_ if from_ is not None \
        else [np.nanmin(x), np.nanmax(x)]
    if m == M:
        return np.ones_like(x) * np.mean( to )
    return (x - m) * (to[1] - to[0]) \
        / (M - m)  + to[0]


#...............................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":  # standalone test --
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:  # numbers on the command line, may be $(cat myfile)
        x = map( float, sys.argv[1:] )
    else:
        np.random.seed( 0 )
        x = np.random.exponential( size=20 )

    print onelineplot( x )
```

Answer (score 8):

Also, [spark](https://zachholman.com/spark/) is a nice little bar graph in your shell.

Answer (score 7):

[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is the definitive answer to your question.

I am personally also a big fan of the [google chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/), which can be accessed from the command line with the help of wget (or curl) to download a png file (and view with xview or something similar).  I like this option because I find the charts to be slightly prettier (i.e. better antialiasing).

Comment: The [Google Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts) is deprecated, but amazing.

Answer (score 6):

Another simpler/lighter alternative to gnuplot is [ervy](https://www.chunqiuyiyu.com/ervy/#started), a NodeJS based terminal charts tool.

Supported types: scatter (XY points), bar, pie, bullet, donut and gauge.

Usage examples with various options can be found on the projects [GitHub repo](https://github.com/chunqiuyiyu/ervy/blob/master/demo/index.js)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found a tool called `ttyplot` in homebrew. It's good. https://github.com/tenox7/ttyplot

Answer (score 5):

You should use gnuplot and be sure to issue the command "set term dumb"
after starting up.  You can also give a row and column count.
Here is the output from gnuplot if you issue "set term dumb 64 10"
and then "plot sin(x)":

```
 

    1 ++-----------****-----------+--***-------+------****--++
  0.6 *+          **+  *          +**   *      sin(x)*******++
  0.2 +*         *      *         **     **         *     **++
    0 ++*       **       *       **       *       **       *++
 -0.4 ++**     *         **     **         *      *         *+
 -0.8 ++ **   *     +      *   ** +         *  +**          +*
   -1 ++--****------+-------***---+----------****-----------++
     -10           -5             0            5             10
```

It looks better at 79x24 (don't use the 80th column on an 80x24 display:  some curses implementations don't always behave well around the last column).

I'm using gnuplot v4, but this should work on slightly older or newer versions.

Answer (score 3):

[termplotlib](https://github.com/nschloe/termplotlib) (one of my projects) has picked up popularity lately, so perhaps this is helpful for some people.

```py
import termplotlib as tpl
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(0, 2 * numpy.pi, 10)
y = numpy.sin(x)

fig = tpl.figure()
fig.plot(x, y, label="data", width=50, height=15)
fig.show()
```

```
    1 +---------------------------------------+
  0.8 |    **     **                          |
  0.6 |   *         **           data ******* |
  0.4 | **                                    |
  0.2 |*              **                      |
    0 |                 **                    |
      |                                   *   |
 -0.2 |                   **            **    |
 -0.4 |                     **         *      |
 -0.6 |                              **       |
 -0.8 |                       **** **         |
   -1 +---------------------------------------+
      0     1    2     3     4     5    6     7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my patch for eplot that adds a -T option for terminal output:

```
--- eplot       2008-07-09 16:50:04.000000000 -0400
+++ eplot+      2017-02-02 13:20:23.551353793 -0500
@@ -172,7 +172,10 @@
                                        com=com+"set terminal postscript color;\n"
                                        @o["DoPDF"]=true

-                               # ---- Specify a custom output file
+                               when /^-T$|^--terminal$/
+                                       com=com+"set terminal dumb;\n"
+
+                                # ---- Specify a custom output file
                                when /^-o$|^--output$/
                                        @o["OutputFileSpecified"]=checkOptArg(xargv,i)
                                        i=i+1

                                    i=i+1
```

Using this you can run it as `eplot -T` to get ASCII-graphics result instead of a gnuplot window.

Comment: eplot now has this built-in with `-d`

Answer (score 2):

The new kid on the block: [`YouPlot`](https://github.com/red-data-tools/YouPlot).