# plot data from CSV file with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a CSV file at `e:\dir1\datafile.csv`.
It contains three columns and 10 heading and trailing lines need to be skipped.
I would like to plot it with numpy.loadtxt(), for which I haven't found any rigorous documentation.

Here is what I started to write from the several tries I found on the web.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

def read_datafile(file_name):
    # the skiprows keyword is for heading, but I don't know if trailing lines
    # can be specified
    data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', skiprows=10)
    return data

data = read_datafile('e:\dir1\datafile.csv')

x = ???
y = ???

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Mains power stability")    
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Mains voltage')

ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='the data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248812/matplotlib-basic-plotting-from-text-file

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) `numpy.loadtxt` is

> a fast reader for simply formatted files. The genfromtxt function provides more sophisticated handling of, e.g., lines with missing values.

so there are only a few options to handle more complicated files.
As mentioned [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) has more options. So as an example you could use

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('e:\dir1\datafile.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=10,
                     skip_footer=10, names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

to read the data and assign names to the columns (or read a header line from the file with `names=True`) and than plot it with

```
ax1.plot(data['x'], data['y'], color='r', label='the data')
```

I think numpy is quite well documented now. You can easily inspect the docstrings from within [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#introducing-ipython) or by using an IDE like [`spider`](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) if you prefer to read them rendered as HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I downloaded the numpy ref. manual; it has all the information I need about genfromtxt.

Comment: nice to hear. On Stackoverflow you would normally upvote an answer, if it was useful for you (and maybe leaving a comment) and / or accept it if your question is answered.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing

```
x= data[:,0]
y= data[:,1]
```

Comment: Or, alternately, `x, y = data[:,:2].T` (or even `x, y, third_column = data.T` if `data` will always have 3 columns).