# Plotting CSV data in Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am working on a project regarding CSV files. I barely at the start of learning python and its mysteries. I have this piece of code that Looks in a folder, gets all ".csv" files (or ".txt" in this case, this is just how I found all the massive data) and reads out its data. After I import the CSV with `pandas` ( it has 2 columns, `Time` and `Amplitude`) i want to plot the two columns. I know how the plot looks like already ( the data was plotted in MATLAB but my job is to create a software for python). I tried using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545388/plot-data-from-csv-file-with-matplotlib) but I do not know how to make it know that my `X-axis` is `Time` and the `Y-axis` is `Amplitude`

this is my whole code so far

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


print ("Please choose the path to the CSV Files: ")


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
path = askdirectory()

print("\nThe chosen folder is: " + path)

tmp_paths=[] 
data_tables=[] 
data_paths=[] 
file_ext=[] 
file_name=[]
sep_name=[] 




for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):     
    for file in files:                      
        if file.endswith(".txt"):          
             tmp_paths=os.path.join(root,file)  #
             tables=pd.read_csv(tmp_paths, header=5, sep=' ',converters={"Time":float, "Ampl":float}) 
             data_tables.append(tables)     
             data_paths.append(tmp_paths)      
                           

file_ext=[name.split("\\",1)[1] for name in data_paths] 
file_name=[name.split(".txt",1)[0] for name in file_ext]
sep_name=[name.split("-",6) for name in file_name]

plt.plot(data_tables[1],data_tables[0])
plt.show()
```

P.S: When I try to plot it gives me: `KeyError: 'Time'.

## EDIT

1.converted the `data_tables` values to `float` using `pandas`

2.fixed ecopy error in the plot code

After the new Edit I no longer get the `KeyError` but `Time` and `Ampl` give another error saying that the indices are expected to be `integers` not `str` or `slices` and the only values it accepts are `1` or `0`, any other value is `out of index`

Comment: Sounds like your `tables` dict has no key "Time". Do all the files in the directory that are getting parsed have a "Time" column? Do the file column names get passed to `tables` as dict keys?

Comment: @stephenlechner `tables` isn't a `dict`, it is a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: Isn't `tables` meant to be just a temporary variable in the loop? I would expect you to use one of the tables in `data_tables` for plotting. By the way, you can simplify a lot of the path handling by using `pathlib.Path`. For example, that loop could be replaced with just `for file in Path().glob('**/*.txt'):`.

Comment: May I see the output of ` table.info()`

Comment: @stovfl this is what `table.info()` shows:
`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
-2.50301e-006    1000 non-null float64
-69.7396         1000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 15.7 KB`

Comment: @MartinValgur I just noticed that, I am sorry, I will edit and indeed tables in temporary. Anyway After the edit I noticed that I ineed got them to be Float, using the in-built `pandas` converter but the only `range` i could choose was between `1` and `0` , I can`t choose the `data_tables` size - 57 or its values. A graph IS Shown but I do not know if the `1` and `0` actually mean the column number or the actual rows. Do you know any links to some documentation? Thank you!

Comment: @MartinValgur i will take using `pathlib.Path` into consideration, upon further documentation it sounds much easier to use, but I want to do this after I get more of the code done, when I will have to "optimize" it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the pandas Documentation you have plot a DataFrame like that:
To plot all of the columns with labels

```
plt.figure()
data_tables.plot()
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

> [pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization.html)