# matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile() - How to plot multiple graphs into same figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I've got 2 text files with each two columns containing numbers like so:

```
26 0.000342231
27 0.000342231
28 0.000684463
29 0.00136893
30 0.00102669
31 0.00308008
32 0.00308008
33 0.00444901
...
77 0.00102669
79 0.000684463
80 0.000342231
81 0.000342231
82 0.000684463
```

and following python code for plotting:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy, scipy.stats

plt.plotfile('histdata1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), names=('stale block', 'frequency'), marker='o', markersize=5, c='r', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0, markeredgewidth=0, markeredgecolor='w')
plt.plotfile('histdata3.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), names=('stale block', 'frequency'), marker='o', markersize=5, c='g', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0, markeredgewidth=0, markeredgecolor='w')

plt.show()
```

This code generates two plots on different figures - however I'd like to have both graphs on the same figure. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `newfig=False` to the second `plt.plotfile()` set of arguments will stop the second graph being plotted in a different figure. A full example of ths can be found [here.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/plotfile_demo.html)

Comment: Thanks! How can I further achieve a legend of titles for each curve?

Comment: You could try something along the lines of:
`plt.legend()`
`plt.title("Title of Plot")`
`plt.xlabel("X Axis Label")`
`plt.ylabel("Y Axis Label")`
As per the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248812/matplotlib-basic-plotting-from-text-file), but I'm not too sure about that one.