# How to plot files with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have a .dat file that contains two columns of numbers so it looks something like this:

```
111    112
110.9  109
103    103
```

and so on.

I want to plot the two columns against one another. I have never dealt with a .dat file before so I am not sure where to start.

So far I figured out that numpy has something I can use to call.

```
data = numpy.loadtxt('data.DAT')
```

but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: so then you have a 2d array of points ... this has nothing to do with *.dat  file could be anything *.txt would work exactly the same... your real question is "How Do I plot a numpy array?"

Comment: It's easy in `gnuplot` ;^).  `plot 'yourfile.dat' u 1:2` (but of course, that doesn't address the actual question ...)

Comment: You can use Scavis that interfaces NumPy (or JNumeric in Java) as [explained in the Scavis manual](http://jwork.org/scavis/wikidoc/doku.php?id=man:numeric:jnum)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib basic plotting from text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248812/matplotlib-basic-plotting-from-text-file)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Numpy doesn't support plotting by itself. You usually would use [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) for plotting numpy arrays.

If you just want to "look into the file", I think the easiest way would be to use [`plotfile`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plotfile('data.dat', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), 
             names=('col1', 'col2'), marker='o')
plt.show()
```

You can use this function almost like `gnuplot` from within ipython:

```
$ ipython --pylab
...
...
In [1]: plt.plotfile('data.dat', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), 
...                  names=('col1', 'col2'), marker='o')
```

or put it in a shell script and pass the arguments to it to use it directly from your shell

[image: plotfile_example]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely does the job!

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
#data = np.loadtxt("plot_me.dat")
#x,y=np.loadtxt("plot_me.dat",unpack=True) #thanks warren!
#x,y =  zip(*data)
#plot.plot(x, y, linewidth=2.0)
plot.plot(*np.loadtxt("plot_me.dat",unpack=True), linewidth=2.0)
plot.show()
```

[Edit]Thanks for the tip i think its as compact as possible now :P

[image: plot 1]

If you want it to be log10 just call log10 on the nparray)

```
plot.plot(*np.log10(np.loadtxt("plot_me.dat",unpack=True)), linewidth=2.0)
```

[image: log10]

Comment: You can make the code even more concise by using the `unpack` keyword in `loadtxt`:  `x, y = np.loadtxt('plot_me.dat', unpack=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how I could take the log_10 of these columns?

Comment: I think just `plot.plot(*np.log10(np.loadtxt("plot_me.dat",unpack=True)), linewidth=2.0)`