# matplotlib plot creation very slow on a headless server

Tags: python, matplotlib, headless

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (server edition) on my home server and I have Python 2.7.6 installed with matplotlib 1.3.1 using TkAgg as the backend. I'm connecting to it via ssh -Y.

The problem I'm having is that creation of the plot object is very slow. So for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[0,1,2,3,4]
y=[0,1,4,9,16]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

This code takes about 10 seconds to run when it should take a fraction of a second. Notice that it isn't even showing the plot, if I add `plt.show()` it makes no significant difference in time. Running the code in the python interpreter or from a file also makes no difference. The plot does get displayed on my local screen just fine once I wait long enough. Also plotting 5 points or 50 points doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: my guess is that most of that time is spent importing matplotlib and its dependencies.

Comment: If I run it line by line in the python interpreter the import command takes no time, it's just the plt.plot(x,y) command that takes up pretty much the whole ten seconds. Also on my local machine there isn't that lag, so why would it exist on the remote machine?

Comment: TkAgg is a graphical, interactive backend. But your server is headless. Try a different backend.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for which backend to try?

Comment: Your choices are: GTK GTKAgg GTKCairo GTK3Agg GTK3Cairo CocoaAgg MacOSX Qt4Agg TkAgg WX WXAgg Agg Cairo GDK PS PDF SVG. If you're only saving to PNG files, I'd go with Agg. Other than that, I use PDF or SVG depending on the situation.

Comment: I guess I still don't see why it should matter if there is a gui running on the machine so long as all the matplotlib dependencies are installed.

Comment: It's just a guess, but it seems like initializing a gui with buttons and zoom capability and caches and editing functionality, even if it can't be displayed, would take some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @Paul H's answer, this code outputs the plot as a SVG graphic, then displays it using the external `feh` utility.

Setting the backend is important -- check [What is a Backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for more info.

### source

```
import matplotlib
# see http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend
# or
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html
matplotlib.use('Svg')

import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[0,1,2,3,4]
y=[0,1,4,9,16]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('plot.svg')
os.system('feh plot.svg')       # or "eog" for Gnome
```

Comment: But it's already creating the plot and forwarding it over my ssh tunnel, it's just taking way longer than it should.

Comment: You could try tweaking the ssh parameters.  Or, plot directly to the terminal -- fast!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295646/python-ascii-plots-in-terminal

Comment: What makes me that that it isn't the ssh connection is that the command `plt.plot(x,y)` takes 10 seconds but isn't doing any x11 forwarding while `plt.show()` is nearly instantaneous even though it is forwarding the graphics over the ssh connection.

Comment: you need to change the backend away from `TkAgg`. Add `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')`. Be sure it's executed before you import `pyplot`

Comment: Well that did make `plt.plot(x,y)` work much faster, but now `plt.show()` doesn't display the plot.

Comment: `plt.savefig('plot.png')` works but it's kinda a pain to have to open  the plot in an external program each time I want to look at what I've generated.

Comment: I've modified the code so it displays after saving.

Comment: Ah, good thought, although I think I'll use feh instead of eog so I don't have to install the ridiculous number of gnome dependencies.

Comment: Good call. I use 'eog' because the ridiculous dependencies are already installed :) If the answer works for you please mark it Accepted.

Comment: Can you edit the code to include changing the backend? Then I'll accept it.

Comment: I've fleshed out the code and description -- thanks @Yelneerg

Comment: same problem here. following

Comment: `feh` cannot display vector graphics like `.svg` files. You should change that to `.png` or some other raster image format that `feh` can display.