# matplotlib pyplot inline plot in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to generate inline plot instead of plot that popping out in `python3.x`. All of the solution I found when browsing around is with `IPython`/`jupyter notebook`, however, I am running my script using terminal, i.e `python3 <script>.py`, and every time I run `plt.show()` it always popping a new window of the result.

How can I achieve inline plot in this scenario?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295646/python-ascii-plots-in-terminal

Comment: You are asking how to render an image in an ascii terminal. That's not possible. I marked as duplicate of a Q&A showing how to produce ascii plots, which is the closest to what you can achieve.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest To render an image in a terminal (and some terminal emulators) is perfectly possible, and matplotlib backends [might exist already](https://github.com/koppa/matplotlib-sixel). This question should not be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @durum if you think `matplotlib-sixel` will answer this question, you can provide such answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @durum We could also mark as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288421/how-to-plot-a-chart-in-the-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1) instead? (That would also be a good place to tell people about matplotlib-sixel backend.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest came back very very late, but if someone is still struggling with this I added my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62084292/2173750