# Is there a way to print graphs made from matplotlib to a csv?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have some plots made using matplotlib in my code. For example:

```
df.loc[:, 'G010006'].plot(legend = True)
```

Is there a way to then take this graph and write it to a csv or text file?

Comment: Graphs produced via matplotlib are images. It's not clear from the question how you imagine a text file to contain an image?

Comment: Is there a way to take that image and paste it in a csv?

Comment: A csv (comma separated values) is a text file. So my question above remains. Do you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnGkM.png) where a graph is rendered via Ascii characters?

Comment: That would work!

Comment: While I've heard someone talking about a pure Ascii backend for matplotlib once, I'm currently unable to find that. [Similar things exist though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295646/python-ascii-plots-in-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

CSVs are essentially text files (think of the built in Notepad app on your computer), they store one thing only: text.

Unless your intention is to store the RGB (**numerical**) values of every pixel in your figure, CSV is not the format that you are looking for. If the latter is your intention, let me know and I'll link you to previous answers that tackle this.