# Plotting spatial data at the BASH terminal

Tags: linux, bash, python-3.x, ubuntu, gis

I'm writing a program to take the output from spatial data queries and plot the points on a world map. I can currently pipe the lat/long from the queries out, but I don't know of a program that would allow me to plot the points in a 1980s-style vector map. I want this program to function all from the terminal without an external GUI.

How would I generate a world map (WGS 84 would be fine) at the bash all on Ubuntu Server using only vector graphics?

Comment: You can't do vector graphics on a terminal. Do you mean character-based graphics, usually colloquially called ASCII graphics (possibly as rasterisation of a vector canvas)? Possible duplicate of [Command-line Unix ASCII-based charting / plotting tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123378/command-line-unix-ascii-based-charting-plotting-tool)

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the advise. I considered character-based graphics, but it would be hard to distinguish between the points and the borders on the map. Given that terminal screens are generally not that big, it would make the end application difficult to use. I'm going for something like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Vf3v6Nh-KST01qNjlsd0FBQ3c/view?usp=sharing). I was looking at GDAL, OGR, and Python tools that might help produce such a view. Any thoughts?