# Plotting to the terminal in python

Tags: python, gnuplot

I'm trying to pick a plotting library to plot data in the terminal, in ASCII format.

In python there are many wrappers for gnuplot but all seems to fall short on the list of requirements:

- support python2 and python3
- wrap parameters and commands properly instead of being just a thin execution layer
- avoid writing down to file system

Also I would like something that is platform indipendent and relying on gnuplot seems to be a deal breaker. This is a nice-to-have, not a strict requirement.

Any suggestion?

I would like to avoid writing my own wrapper and add noise to the ecosystem but the options available seem too rough.

Comment: What do  you need to plot? ;)

Comment: I want to be open to as many possibilities as I can. For now unidimensional and bidimensional data in general, both on a cartesian plane, and as histograms (for unidimensional). In the future I may need graphs but I already saw there are some options for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123378/command-line-unix-ascii-based-charting-plotting-tool

Comment: gnuplot doesn't work with python3. I developed my MVP with it and now I need to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:
https://github.com/mzechmeister/python/wiki/gplot.py

- supports python2/python3/jupyter
- supports all commands
- option how to transmit data (see parameter `tmp`: tmpfiles, datablock, etc.)

```
>>> from gplot import *
>>> gplot.term("dumb")
<gplot.Gplot object at 0x7fd394c17d10>
>>> gplot('sin(x)')
>>> 

    1 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+   
      |               ** **              +  ** **         +       *  *     |   
  0.8 |-+             *   **               **   *           sin(x*********-|   
      |              **    *               *    **               *    *    |   
  0.6 |-+            *     **              *     *              *      * +-|   
      |              *      *             **     **             *      *   |   
  0.4 |*+           *       *             *       *             *       *+-|   
      |*            *        *           **       *            *        *  |   
  0.2 |*+          **        *           *         *           *        *+-|   
      | *          *         *           *         *          **         * |   
    0 |-*          *          *         **         *          *          *-|   
      | *         **          *         *           *         *          * |   
 -0.2 |-+*        *           *         *           *        **          +*|   
      |  *        *            *       **           *        *            *|   
 -0.4 |-+*       *             *       *             *       *           +*|   
      |   *      *             **     **             *      *              |   
 -0.6 |-+ *      *              *     *              **     *            +-|   
      |    *    *               **    *               *    **              |   
 -0.8 |-+  *   **                *   **               **   *             +-|   
      |     *  *       +         ** **   +             ** **               |   
   -1 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+   
     -10              -5                 0                5               10   


>>>
```